# How can I fix linq to sql predicate static method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working on the ***linq-to-sql***. This is my current code:

```
 var search = Controller.PredicateBuilder.False<Model.view_faturalar>();

        search = search.Or(x => x.faturutipi.ToString().Equals("1"));
```

This code gives me the following error:

> Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
>       Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'Or' takes 1 arguments   ...\Faturalar.cs    108

How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you mean `search = search.Or(x => x.faturutipi == "1");` ?

Comment: yes, but not working

Comment: What is Or? is this your extension method?